# How to write app for Firefox OS

Tags: mobile-os, firefox-os

I want to write my app for [Firefox OS](http://blog.mozilla.org/blog/2012/07/02/firefox-mobile-os/).  What kind of languages (like Java for Android and Objective C++ for iOS) and tools (like Eclipse, Xcode) to use?

Comment: The most important part is having a manifest file. This way you can distribute your html application to the user interface (Gaia) or any other OS since Firefox 16.
More information on building a manifest file can be found at the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Apps/Manifest)

Comment: I created a basic, working Firefox OS app here: https://github.com/darkwing/html5apptut I'll also be writing blog posts about this very topic here: http://davidwalsh.name/tutorials/firefoxos

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Apps for Firefox OS (previously known as Boot to Gecko) are developed using HTML 5 and Javascript.

References:

http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/b2g/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mozilla/Boot_to_Gecko/

You can use any web development tool you like. Firefox has a lot of built-in tools to check out: https://marketplace.mozilla.org/developers/docs/devtools The responsive mode tool is very useful for Firefox OS / mobile apps.

Besides tools, the most important skills to learn are techniques for building web apps: https://marketplace.mozilla.org/developers/docs/references

Comment: I also find these building blocks extremely useful: http://buildingfirefoxos.com/building-blocks/

Answer (score 2):

If you are a web developer, then I must say you are the master of Firefox OS already! It's all about HTML5, CSS and Javascript. Any development tool like Eclipse, Visual Studio, Notepad++, WebStorm and etc. can be used. But there is one and only difference between Web application and Firefox OS application. You have to add a [manifest.webapp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/Manifest) file in the root directory of your project. Let say your project files are like following

1. css
2. js
3. index.html

Now you have to add a manifest.webapp file in above and it should look like following

```
{
  "name": "My App",
  "description": "My elevator pitch goes here",
  "launch_path": "/index.html",
  "icons": {
    "512": "/img/icon-512.png",
    "128": "/img/icon-128.png"
  },
  "developer": {
    "name": "Your name or organization",
    "url": "http://your-homepage-here.org"
  },
  "default_locale": "en"
}
```

So your app is ready! What's next? App deployment ......

You can deploy your app as following ways..

[Packaged App](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Marketplace/Options/Packaged_apps) : All files will reside inside in your mobile
[Hosted app](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Marketplace/Options/Hosted_apps) : Files will be hosted in a remote server like IIS, Apache and etc. Mobile will know the manifest.webapp file URL only.

And that's all about firefox os app development. I hope this post will help future beginner as I am very late to answer this question.